# How to understand "as $x$ tends to $a$, value $c$ also tends to $a$" at the proof L'Hospital's Rule using Cauchy theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, mean-value-theorem

- When I read the proof of L'Hospital's Rule, the exact meaning of "x tends to a" made me confused.
- I'll write briefly about the proof:
  [image]

[image]

> $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+}g(x) = 0$  and $f(a) = g(a) = 0$
> according to Cauchy Theorem $ \exists c \in (a,x) , \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f '(c)}{g'(c)} $

> **As x tends to a from the right, the value c also tends to a from the right,
> and the desired conclusion follows:**

> $ \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\lim_{c\to a^+} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=L$

- My first question: I can feel "let x tends to a then c tends to a" or "let $x \to a^+,then\  c \to a^+$"  means when x get closer to a, then c close to a.What is the exact meaning of this?Can this translate into exact math languge?I don't think that's very precise.
- My second question: $\forall x>a, \exists c \in (a,x), \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f '(c)}{g'(c)} $ Using this property, how to get "$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\lim_{c\to a^+} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$",just let x tends to a from the right? I think there are some steps that are missing.

Comment: Can you please write out the *entire* proof and point to the part that you're confused about?

Comment: Since $c$ depends on $x$, better denote it by $c(x).$ Since $c(x)\in(a,x)$, it is clear that "As $x$ tends to $a$ from the right, the value $c$ also tends to $a$ from the right", i.e. that $\lim_{x\to a^+}c(x)=a^+.$ This answers your first question.

Comment: In your second question, the first and third expression are exactly the same by changing the variable x to c.

Comment: @Benjamin Wang I added the whole proof and underline my confusion.

Comment: Generally, when something tends to something else, it means we can make the distance between the two arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Divide1918 Sorry , it's my fault, third expression is f'(c) and g'(c)

Comment: In your second question, the first equality results from the choice of $c,$ and the second one, better written $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'}{g'}(c(x))=\lim_{c\to a^+}\frac{f'}{g'}(c)$ is a direct application of the theorem on composition of limits (and of the answer above to your first question).

Comment: To augment @AnneBauval's comment: instead of "it is clear that", I prefer "by the squeeze theorem".

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your reply! I got it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3586275/72031